# In which format should I pass image from Rust to JS?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, rust, webassembly

I'm trying to pass image from JS to Rust, process it and return back from Rust to JS. Please, help me to understand in which format should I return image from Rust.

My JS code look like this:

```js
import { Image } from "image_processing";

const input = document.getElementById('image-input')
const image_canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas')

input.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
    const buffer = await event.target.files[0].arrayBuffer();
    const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    const image = Image.new(view);
    console.log('xxx1', view);

    const imageBlob = image.get_image_blob();
    console.log('xxx2', imageBlob);

    const blob = new Blob(imageBlob, { type: 'image/jpeg'});
    console.log('xxx3', blob);


    image_canvas.width = image.get_width();
    image_canvas.height = image.get_height();
    const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(blob, 0, 0, image_canvas.width, image_canvas.height);
    const context = image_canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
});
```

And Rust `Image.new` and `Image.get_image_blob` functions looks like this:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Image {
    pub fn new(image_blob: Vec<u8>) -> Image {
        let reader = Reader::new(io::Cursor::new(image_blob))
            .with_guessed_format()
            .expect("Cursor io never fails");

        let extension = match reader.format() {
            Some(extension) => extension,
            None => panic!("Can't guess image extension")
        };

        let width;
        let height;
        let image = match reader.decode() {
            Ok(image) => {
                let (w, h) = image.dimensions();
                
                width = w;
                height = h;
  
                image
            },
            Err(error) => {
                panic!("Can't get image: {}", error)
            }
        };

        Image {
            image,
            width,
            height,
            extension,
        }
    }
    
    .
    .
    .

    pub fn get_image_blob(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        match self.extension {
            x if x == ImageFormat::Png => self.image.to_rgba8().to_vec(),
            _ => self.image.to_rgb8().to_vec()
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to process jpeg image in browser console I get this:
[image: browser console output]

It's look like my returning blob from `get_image_blob` is incorrect. Before I process my image with Rust it has right file signature for jpeg: [255, 216, 255, ...]. But after processing it became [162, 162, 152, ...]. I assume that I should try changing `to_rgb8` method on something else, but I can't understand why. Can you help me and explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Turns out that signature changes when I call `decode` method, but I still don't know why.

Comment: What is `Reader`?

Comment: @eggyal `Struct` from `image` library – https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/io/struct.Reader.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decode method take a JPEG file and returns the raw pixels as an uncompressed block of memory. In other words, the [162, 162, 152...] means that the top right pixel has value red=162, green=162, and blue=152. You can make image from raw byte data by using [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) or by encoding that data with help of [image::codecs::jpeg::JpegEncoder.encode](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/codecs/jpeg/struct.JpegEncoder.html#method.encode) or [save_buffer_with_format](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/fn.save_buffer_with_format.html) methods. For more information you can read this [issue](https://github.com/image-rs/image/issues/1610).